# How to get blob from some table in oracle db and generate file using sqlplus

Tags: oracle, blob, sqlplus

I have a problem with SqlPlus. I would like to get blob from Oracle DB and generate file with this data on client side. It can be image, sound or text data.

I know about `spool` command....

```
spool on
spool file.txt
select blob_data from some_table where id = 1234;
spool off
```

...it writes data to file. But spooled data is presented as text,  not binary.
Does anybody knows the way how to get blob data from Oracle DB on client side and generate file with this data? Thank you.

Comment: What to do want to do with the spooled data? You could write is as base-64-encoded text, and then post-process that back to a plain binary file on the client side too, i suppose.

Comment: I would like to generate file using spooled data, it might an image, text file or something else. It seems that SqlPlus doesn't provide this feature.

Comment: It will only spool printable characters, and as your binary data is going to have unprintable bytes, you need to encode it into text. You could dump the RAW data as text, but base-64 is probably simpler to decode. You may even be able to do that from your script via a host command, depending on your client platform and the tools available. (I'm assuming it has to be on the client side, and the file can't be created on the server?)